# In Lisp, how do you call a function from a macro, by name passed as an argument?

Tags: function, variables, lisp, common-lisp

In Lisp, how do you call, from a macro, a function whose name is the symbol value of a symbol? I might be wrong but I think I'm right that a symbol is a variable.

Here is what I currently have:

```
(defmacro cfunc (a b) (list a b))
(defparameter foo 'my-func)
(defun my-func (data) '(some-code))
(cfunc foo data) ;does not work    
(cfunc my-func data) ;works
```

I'm thinking I need to add some special character in front of `foo` to evaluate to its symbol value before being treated as a function. `(cfunc foo data)` creates and calls the function `(foo data)` instead of `(my-func data)`. I suppose I could change the function defining in `cfunc` instead.

`#'foo` doesn't work, that gives `(function foo)` which `cfunc` returns and calls `((function foo) data)`. `(symbol-value foo)` can't work either. So I'm thinking I can't change what is given to `cfunc` but I can change the code of the function `cfunc` makes.

If someone has a specific page of a resource that tells me about evaluation and expansion using `defmacro` or the specifics of the special characters like `#` and `'` or know the keywords I should be looking up, I'd appreciate it if that could be shared as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in the form `(cfunc foo data)`, to what do you expect that `data` refers? I don't see any definition of it here. It's only mentioned incidentally as a parameter to the `my-func` function, which doesn't come into play for your expansion of `cfunc`. Perhaps you expect `data` to be available later as a special variable.

In any case, the problem you're running into is that Common Lisp is a "Lisp-2"; a variable present at the head of a [*function form*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_f.htm#function_form) doesn't automatically have its *function cell* accessed to coerce it to a function. In your case, `foo` is *not* a function bound in the environment; it's a variable whose value is a symbol (`my-func`)—one that in turn is bound to a function. To navigate this extra level of indirection, you have to request that that symbol's function cell be accessed, either via `funcall` or, in other cases, `function`.

Here are a few observations from the REPL:

```
> (symbol-value 'foo)
MY-FUNC
> (ignore-errors (symbol-function 'foo))
NIL
#<UNDEFINED-FUNCTION FOO {1004E22D23}>
> (fboundp 'foo)
NIL

> (ignore-errors (symbol-value 'my-func))
NIL
#<UNBOUND-VARIABLE MY-FUNC {1005324E93}>
> (symbol-function 'my-func)
#<FUNCTION MY-FUNC>
> (fboundp 'my-func)
T
```

Here we see that the symbol `foo` has a *value binding*—meaning it's a *variable*—but it has no function binding. Following `foo` through to `my-func`, we see that `my-func` has no value binding, but it does have a function binding.

To wrap up, your `cfunc` macro needs be written as follows:

```
(defmacro cfunc (a b)
  (list 'funcall a b))
```

Alternately, you can write it like this:

```
(defmacro cfunc (a b)
  `(funcall ,a ,b))
```

You mentioned originally that the form

```
(cfunc my-func data)
```

works as intended. With my proposed revision above, it won't work any longer, because now `my-func` is being treated as a value to be evaluated as an argument to `funcall`, when in fact it has no value cell (as it's a function). Hence, you'll have to adapt the form to the following:

```
(cfunc #'my-func data)
```

That's saying, "Look up the symbol 'my-func' in the function namespace, grab its value, and supply that function as an argument."

For a more precise treatment on the difference in handling such symbols-pointing-to-functions in Lisp-1 and -2, see Gabriel's [*Technical Issues of Separation in Function Cells and Value Cells*](http://www.nhplace.com/kent/Papers/Technical-Issues.html)—in particular, section 5, "Notational Simplicity".

Comment: Thanks a bunch, `data` just refers to the parameters for the function made by `cfunc`. So one problem was having the variable name as the first item in the list in `cfunc` and the second one was accessing the function value of the value of the symbol. `foo` has the value of `my-func` and `my-func` has the function value of the function I want

Comment: I revised the answer to use more precise language for things like bindings, variables, values, and functions.